# CodeIgniter issue with base_url in form

Tags: forms, codeigniter, base-url

I called `base_url()` in the form action in a view in my local machine. But, it is giving the url as `http://::1/codeigniter/` instead of `http://localhost/codeigniter`. This is the same case with the `site_url()` also.

Is it a problem with the `.htaccess` file or should I make any settings in `config.php`?

Below is my `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

I am using CodeIgniter 3.0 version.

Comment: whats there in config.php file?

Comment: What is the value of `$config['base_url']` in config?

Comment: I didn't make any changes in config.php. I am asking if I should any setting in that file.

Comment: @deepakb : Its null. $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: If you leave it blank the framework will try to autodetect it since version 2.0.0. Try to set that value in config and I think everything works.

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter'`. Set this in your config and check if it working!

Comment: Perfect..!! Its working. Thanks a lot @deepakb

Comment: Put trailing slash at the end. It is written in description in file just above the line. `URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL, WITH a trailing slash: http://example.com/ WARNING: You MUST set this value!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave it blank the framework will try to autodetect it since version 2.0.0. Try to set that value in config: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/'` and I think everything should works.

*Edit: with trailing slash.*

Comment: With version 3.0.x auto detection should not be relied on. It should always be configured in config.php

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-19-make-sure-your-base-url-config-value-is-not-empty

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change `$config['base_url']` , while changing the server or moving the project to a live server from local machine , try this :

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$root";
```

> This can possibly avoid all issues with `$config['base_url']` .